# how does webpack process this module shimming pattern?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, imports-loader, exports-loader

webpack's documentation lists an interesting pattern for shimming a module that sets properties on `window`, like `window.XModule = {...}`.

https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#the-file-sets-a-property-on-window-window-xmodule

```
require('imports?window=>{}!exports?window.XModule!./file.js')
```

Applying the pattern to ES6, I ended up with this:

```
import XMODULE from 'imports?window=>{}!exports?window.XModule!./file.js'
```

I'm trying to understand how Webpack processes this statement, specifically, what role the `imports-loader` part plays, `imports?window=>{}`. I understand that the `exports-loader` basically sets `XMODULE` to be `window.XModule` from the dependency. As for the `imports-loader`, it seems like all it does is not allow the `window` object to get polluted by the dependency... but how?

How does `imports?window=>{}` work in conjuction with `exports?window.XModule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question. Firstly, the order of the loaders matters (`expose-loader` before `imports-loader` before `exports-loader`):

https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html#order-of-loaders

Regarding the specific example in my question...

`'imports?window=>{}!exports?window.XModule!./file.js'`

webpack will run the `imports-loader` and insert the following at the beginning of the module:

```
/*** IMPORTS FROM imports-loader ***/
var window = {};
```

webpack will run the `exports-loader` and insert the following at the end of the module:

```
/*** EXPORTS FROM exports-loader ***/
exports["XModule"] = (window.XModule);
```